# Equation is returning a solution in WolframAlpha, but giving a logical zero in MATLAB. How can I fix this?

Tags: matlab, wolframalpha

Here is the equation [in WolframAlpha returning me the correct answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+((1+%2B+(1%2F605)*x)%5E(121%2F122))*((1+-+(1%2F5)*x)%5E(1%2F122))+-+0.20+%3D+0+for+x).

In MATLAB, I've written the following:

mu = 305; %as a temporary example since it's greater than c, which is 300

```
syms x
eqn = ((1 + (x/(mu + 300)))^((1/2) + (150/mu)))*((1 - (x/(mu - 300)))^((1/2) - (150/mu))) - 0.2 == 0 %matlab shows the answer is -605
solve(eqn,x)
```

It's the same equation, except MATLAB substitutes for mu for me. MATLAB is returning the following:

```
eqn = logical 0
ans = x
```

Am I typing the equation in wrong somehow? Is that why it's showing me a logical zero when I'm not suppressing the equation? How do I get it to result in the same values as WolframAlpha?

I also want to note that Maple seems to hang on this same equation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a specific reason for using symbolic expressions, you can solve the equation that you have using [fsolve](https://in.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html) as follows:

```
%Define your value of mu
mu = 305;
% Define the equation as an anonymous function
fn = @(x) ((1 + (x/(mu + 300)))^((1/2) + (150/mu)))*((1 - (x/(mu - 300)))^((1/2) - (150/mu))) - 0.2;
% Define the initial value for x so that fsolve can find the root nearest to that
x0 = 1;
root_x = fsolve(fn, x0);
```

This leads to the output `root_x = 5.0000 + 0.0000i`
You can also change the initial value of x0

```
x0 = 400;
root_x = fsolve(fn, x0);
```

This will return the output `root_x = -4.9005e+02 - 2.6326e-05i`

This method can be used to solve any of the equations that you might have.